# Loop / Iterate a set of records and execute a stored proc

Tags: sql-server

Reading a lot of articles about the evil of cursors but to me it seems as though it would be good way to go if the cursor is read only and forward only.  Am I right in thinking that this would not cause locks.

I need to select a group of records and iterate through them performing an action if the row has a certain value.  The acrion will be a stored proc and will insert a copy of the current row into the same table with some updated dates).  There could be a lot of these rows so I am looking for the most efficient way possible.

Can anybody suggest the most efficient approach to this sort of problem?

Comment: Can you explain with some sample data

Comment: Cursors not always the performance killer, but it is hard to debug. Try convert the loop to set-based logic as far as possible, make use of staging tables to do the update works.

Comment: *"I want to take some rows, update some dates and then reinsert to the same table"* can definitely be achieved with set based logic.  There is almost certainly no need for a cursor here.

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking into

- CTE's https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/
- APPLY operators https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

for e.g.

```
WITH 
  cteTotalSales (SalesPersonID, NetSales)
  AS
  (
    SELECT SalesPersonID, ROUND(SUM(SubTotal), 2)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID
  )
SELECT 
  sp.FirstName + ' ' + sp.LastName AS FullName,
  sp.City + ', ' + StateProvinceName AS Location,
  ts.NetSales
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson AS sp
  INNER JOIN cteTotalSales AS ts
    ON sp.BusinessEntityID = ts.SalesPersonID
ORDER BY ts.NetSales DESC
```

Hope it helps!